# Reverse not found in Django

Tags: python, django

This might be a simple one but I have been on this for hours, I must be missing something. Here we go:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
# Event patterns
url('^$', views.BuddyProgram.as_view(), name='buddy_program'),
url('^dashboard/$', views.BuddyDashboard.as_view(), name='buddy_dashboard'),
url('^thank-you/$', views.BuddyFinal.as_view(), name='final'),

url('^completed_intro/$', views.CompletedIntro.as_view(), name='buddy_completed_intro'),
url('^completed_passive_track/$', views.CompletedPassiveTrack.as_view(), name='buddy_completed_passive_track'),
url('^about/$', views.BuddyAbout.as_view(), name='buddy_about'),
url('^list/$', views.Buddies.as_view(model=BuddyProfile), name='buddies'),
url('^signup/$', views.BuddySignupView.as_view(), name='buddy_signup'),

# url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<buddy_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.Buddy.as_view(model=BuddyProfile), name='buddy'),
```

]

views.py:

```
class BuddyFinal(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'buddy/thank_you.html'

class BuddySignupView(SignupView):

    template_name = 'buddy/buddy_create.html'
    success_url = reverse('final')  # profile specific success url
    form_class = BuddySignupForm
    profile_class = BuddyProfile  # profile class goes here

    def form_valid(self, form):

        response = super(BuddySignupView, self).form_valid(form)
        profile = self.profile_class(user=self.user)

        profile.save()

        return response
```

and the error I get:

```
 django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'final' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Your URL registration hasn't completed yet by the time you load the `BuddySignupView` class. Don't look up the `success_url` reverse until you actually completed URL registrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your URLs aren't loaded yet when importing the BuddySignupView (and thus executing `reverse`), Django cannot find the URL.

You should use `reverse_lazy` instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

In your `views.py` file:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class BuddySignupView(SignupView):

    template_name = 'buddy/buddy_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('final')  # profile specific success url
```

`reverse_lazy` only reverse the URL name at "runtime" (when Django actually needs the value) instead of "import time" when everything may not be available yet.

Comment: It did work but a couple lines up in the views I have `class BuddyProgram(RedirectView):` that uses `reverse` and it works. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: @mgPePe I can't say without seeing the code. Maybe the line is not called on import time (ie you are using a `def get_success_url()` or something similar, only called at runtime)? Or it refers to another URL name that may have already been imported?

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming `because in any template file you are accecsing url(thank-you or signup) in wrong format.` make sure about this url in html.